# Version 2.83 normals not working

Tags: normals

i'm using V2.83.
when i turn on normals in Overlays, all the normals are pointing X axis and pink.
face orientation is on.[image]

Comment: It's the split normals, they have been changed for some reason, go into the Object Data panel > Geometry Data > click on  Clear Custom Split Normals Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the split normals, they have been changed for some reason, go into the *Object Data* panel > *Geometry Data* > click on *Clear Custom Split Normals Data*.

Comment: thanks so much!!